# How true-to-life is the language used by Issa and Molly?

Tags: insecure

The main characters of the HBO show *Insecure* are a 29-year-old black woman named Issa, who works at a non-profit, and her friend Molly, a successful corporate attorney who is also a young black woman.

[According to IndieWire](http://www.indiewire.com/2016/08/insecure-teaser-issa-rae-hbo-comedy-series-1201720766/), the show "explores the black female experience in an unclichéd and authentic way." The actress Issa Rae, who plays the character Issa, is one of the creators of the show.

On the show, the two main characters repeatedly (perhaps even *incessantly*) use the word "bitch" to refer to each other when conversing. They also frequently use the word "nigga."

How true-to-life is this dialogue? Specifically, are the two terms above used that commonly by the demographic represented by Issa and Molly?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for asking this question. I am disgusted by the language on the show and it is in NO WAY reflective of how I speak with my friends.

This is what I posted on the 'Insecure' FB page this weekend:

Ugh! I really wanted to like this show... I did. But, I'm officially out. This woman finally gets a show on HBO and she chooses to litter the script with N-words and B**ch. I have NEVER referred to any of my Black friends as N-word this or that. What's more disturbing, this woman majored in African American studies at Stanford! She knows better. Again, I wanted to like this show, but I will NOT support any "work" that reinforces stereotypes and degrades Black women. 
Stay woke people.

Comment: Just a thought: Would your very valid comments apply to all demographics?